# MacBook Pro does not sleep/require password at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, password

I just bought a brand new MacBook Pro: a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports).

**And here is the issue:** It will not sleep/require password automatically pretty much at all. This is both a battery saving issue and a security issue for me.

My settings are as follows:

- Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver.
- Disable automatic login
- Turn display off after 1 minute when using battery
- Turn display off after 1 minute when using power adapter

I've had mixed results, and noticed this behavior is not deterministic. I'm really frustrated that my brand new MacBook Pro is behaving this way, and I'm considering returning it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/309987/edit) your question to clarify whether the issue is actually that your MBP is **not** going to sleep, or whether it's just not requiring the password *after* sleep? If it's not going to sleep, then that explains why it's not requiring your password, and we need to figure out why it's not going to sleep. If it is going to sleep, then we know the issue is more about requiring the password rather than it not going to sleep.

Comment: @Monomeeth it is not going to sleep. It does require the password after sleep

Comment: Okay, so the real issue is that it's not going to sleep. The password requirement is probably just not happening because it's not going to sleep, rather than an issue with the password itself. My first suggestion would be to reset the SMC as per zipzit's answer. Let us know if that doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible System Management Controller (SMC) issue?  Can you try a SMC reset and test your conditions again?

[Link here...](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

What the SMC does.  The SMC is responsible for these and other low-level functions on Intel-based Mac computers:

- Responding to presses of the power button
- Responding to the display lid opening and closing on Mac notebooks
- Battery management
- Thermal management
- Sudden Motion Sensor (SMS)
- Ambient light sensing
- Keyboard backlighting
- Status indicator light (SIL) management
- Battery status indicator lights
- Selecting an external (instead of internal) video source for some iMac displays

Comment: Yup. I came back to my not asleep computer after an hour away, was really fed up so I checked back on this thread, followed the steps, and it appears to be working. Hopefully the fix is permanent. I suspect the addition of the touch ID sensor.